# How to add a target to a button added to a View? Detail: View is controlled variable within a Class

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I am organizing a code an app that iPad Air 2 I use to control finances of a company (as a developer without AppStore). This app displays painels with information, and these panels are displayed and hidden as the user action.

I decided to try to create different ways and separate my schedule between arquivos.swift.

That's my ViewController. Only two buttons, it's all I do for Interface Builder (for example). The rest of the application is created programmatically.

[image]

This ViewController is connected directly to the ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    var panelInfo: PanelInfo!

    var selfSize: CGSize {
        get {
            return self.view.frame.size
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        panelInfo = PanelInfo(viewControllerSize: selfSize)
        self.view.addSubview(panelInfo.panel)
    }


    @IBAction func showPropNavigationbar(sender: AnyObject) {
        panelInfo.show()
    }

    @IBAction func hidePropNavigationbar(sender: AnyObject) {
        panelInfo.hide()
    }

}
```

To create a view that will be displayed where the information, I created a class that manages it.

```
class PanelInfo {

    /*** View Controller Size ***/
    private var viewSize: CGSize!

    /*** View ***/
    internal var panel: UIView!

    /*** View Panel Size ***/
    private var size: CGSize!

    /*** View Position ***/
    private var originShow: CGPoint!
    private var originHide: CGPoint!

    private var closeButton: UIButton!

    /*** Start the instance ***/
    init(viewControllerSize: CGSize) {

        /*** Set values in variables above ***/
        viewSize = viewControllerSize
        size = CGSize(width: 300, height: viewSize.height)
        originShow = CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - size.width, y: 0)
        originHide = CGPoint(x: viewSize.width, y: 0)

        /*** Create the panel view ***/
        panel = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: originHide, size: self.size))
        panel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.014, green: 0.106, blue: 0.179, alpha: 1.000)

        /*** Create the closeButton ***/
        closeButton = UIButton(type: .System)
        closeButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 8, y: 8), size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32))
        closeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "closeButton"), forState: .Normal)
        panel.addSubview(closeButton)
    }

    func hidepanel(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(sender)
        self.hide()
    }

    /*** Show panel in ViewController ***/
    internal func show() -> Void {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
            self.panel.frame.origin = self.originShow
        }
    }

    /*** Hide panel in ViewController ***/
    internal func hide() -> Void {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
            self.panel.frame.origin = self.originHide
        }
    }

}
```

When the code is executed, and I touch in 'Show', the panel appears. Working perfectly.

When I touch in 'Hide', the panel disappears. Working perfectly.

[image]

## **The Problem**

I'm trying to create a button for programming and add a target to run make the panel close. This button is closeButton.

---

If i added the target (nil, action: "hidepanel:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside

Nothing happens

---

If I change for closeButton.addTarget(nil, action: "hidepanel:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside

Nothing happens

---

If I change for closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "hidepanel:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

The error appear:

*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7a99ee00 of class 'Panel_Model.PanelInfo' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Panel_Model.PanelInfo hide panel:]

---

If I try change for closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "hidepanel", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

The previous error appears

---

> Note: This is a example. The app original is bigger. When I started to build the app, had little time to do it and had little experience in Swift (and Obj-C as well), so I created everything needed in a ViewController. Today I am with almost 5000 lines of programming, and need to find a better way to organize.

I believe that the error can be related to (target: AnyObject?, ...) , the first item of AddTarget, for the reason of being used in a class without superclass... But I can't find a way to solve it.

**My question:**

1º This is the best form of organization?

2º Knowing that I am using a class, and this class have a variabel controlling a UIView. Can I implement added buttons to view and set targets on the buttons?

3º If possible, what is the best way to do this, could show examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 30))
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("hidepanel:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

**Update**

Try inheriting PanelInfo from `NSObject.

Comment: Console show the error: *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7a99ee00 of class 'Panel_Model.PanelInfo' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector -[Panel_Model.PanelInfo hide panel:].

Comment: Do you have any alternative to this code? I tried using Tap Gesture, but I can't get a good result.

Comment: I believe that the error can be related to (target: AnyObject?, ...) , the first item of AddTarget, for the reason of being used in a class without superclass...

Comment: @James - Have you implemented the methods `hidepanel:` in the same target?

Comment: @James - Try inheriting PanelInfo from NSObject. That could be the problem.